# What are the minimum spec requirements for 2.8?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have tried using Eevee on my computer, but it kept crashing. It was a version that was downloaded a couple of weeks ago. Also, I attempted to use Substance Designer and it failed to work as well. My computer is just a standard laptop with no special additions to it. I went to the [requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) page and it said the following:

> Note: These requirements are valid for Blender 2.77 up to 2.79b. However, Blender 2.76 and earlier still supports Windows XP and OpenGL 1.4 graphics cards. **Blender 2.8 requires OpenGL 3.3 or above.**

Unlike the last time that I check this page almost a year ago, Blender was more explicit about the graphics card requirements. I want to know is OpenGL 3.3 is the common standard for all new computers after a certain date if not, are there indicators for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said it, Eevee is a GPU Boosted engine, it uses features present in >= OpenGL3.3. The fact that you added Substance made it suspicious for a driver issue.  Make sure you have DirectX and .NET for Substance and the latest OpenGL Drivers.

As for your other question, new cards are  mostly OpenGL 4.5 capable. You can check your OpenGL version by going to the dxdiag. And please add more details about your PC specs, it helps us better