# Blender on DELL Poweredge and OpenGL 3.3 Requirement

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am building a render farm at home with old DELL Poweredge R620 servers.

I'm planning to run Linux but to test Blender I quickly loaded Windows 10. Blender when starting hits me with error about OpenGL 3.3 minimum requirement.

Is this also a requirement of Linux as it loads but the screen is missing icons and looks pretty corrupt?

Is there anyway around this or do I have to install an old GPU into each server?

thanks
Dave

Comment: As far as I know, OpenGL is needed for the UI, however you do not need the UI to render with Cycles. If that"s what you are after, you might want to look into rendering from the command line.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118952/what-are-the-minimum-spec-requirements-for-2-8 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119475/will-blender-2-8-official-realise-be-able-to-run-on-computer-with-graphics-drive and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137257/blender-2-8-beta-opengl-3-3-error/137352#137352